# Can't override $navbar-light-color in bootstrap-vue (nuxt)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm attempting to override the `$navbar-light-color` variable in the Bootstrap 4 scss, but it's not working. I can override other variables (e.g., $primary) just fine.

Here is my `main.scss` file:

```
$navbar-light-color: rgba(green, .5);
$primary: orange;

// Required
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Optional
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";

@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/navbar';
@import "~bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import '~bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

In `nuxt.config.js` I have disabled the automatic packaging of the css as instructed in the bootstrap-vue docs.
I've confirmed that it's disabled correctly.

Comment: `$navbar-light-color` affects only the text color, is that what you are trying?  Also, make sure you also set prop `type="light"` on `<b-navbar>` to apply the light styling. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L745-L750

Comment: And you may need to set the following variables as well: `$navbar-light-color`, `$navbar-light-hover-color`, `$navbar-light-active-color`, `$navbar-light-disabled-color` (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L745-L750)

Comment: Well, this is a facepalm moment. I had type="dark" but since dark type is actually light text I my brain was focused on the "light" variables. It works. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try adding `!important`:

```
$navbar-light-color: rgba(green, .5) !important;
```

Comment: You can't add !important to a variable